# Unable to increase size of partition

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, disk-management

I can't increase the size of ext4 or the partition in which Ubuntu is installed , it says that it is in maximum size:
[image: ******]
[image: ******]

Answer (score 1):

Well, that is kind of obvious that there is no free space left or right of your partition. So where do you want to increase its size ?

Your only viable solution is to copy your sda6 partition into the unallocated space of 39GB then once this is done, increase its size to 39GB.
And finally, delete the original sda6 partition.

Comment: This will render the OS unbootable, you have to reinstall Grub if you do that.

Comment: No. Grub is using UUID. It will find the partition even if it moved

Comment: Ah, I forgot about UUID's, sorry...